Find embedded document based on nested embedded document ID in MongoEngine
I have the following schema:
class Feature(EmbeddedDocument):
    feature_name = StringField(required=True)
    geometry = PolygonField(required=True)
    id = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Label(EmbeddedDocument):
    label_name = StringField(required=True)
    version = IntField(required=True)
    features = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Feature)
    id = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Image(Document):
    image_name = StringField(required=True)
    date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    labels = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Label)

Based on a given feature ID (nested embedded document), I would like to find its parent image and label IDs (top-level and embedded documents).
I can find the image ID (top-level document) with this query:
parent_image = Image.objects.filter(labels__features__id=feature_id)[0]

But I can't seem to find the label ID (embedded document) with a similar query:
parent_label = Image.objects.get(id=parent_image.id).labels.filter(features__id=feat_id)[0]

This raises an AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'features__id'.
I don't see yet what's wrong with my second query. Can't I use this syntax on embedded documents?

The issue with your second query is that you're trying to filter on the labels field directly, which returns a list of Label objects, not Feature objects. Since features is a field within each Label object, you need to first iterate over the labels and then filter within each label's features.

Thanks @Anurator.
But didn't I filter on the image fields directly in my first query, and manage to find the parent image nevertheless? How is my second query different from the first? I imagined that MongoEngine is running an aggregation and unwinding embedded docs under the hood.
I managed to find the parent label by iterating manually over labels like so parent_label = [label.features.filter(id=feature.id)[0]._instance for label in Image.objects.get(id=parent_image.id).labels][0].
But I was hoping that MongoEngine would have allowed a more intuitive or readable method.
